# Best Practice - What to do when creating Unit Test with huge amount of entities

Tags: c#

I am creating an unit test, but there are many entities. So do I have to insert all entities at database manually or is there any better solution?

Comment: what do you want to unit test exactly? which technology are you using? Entity Framework, NHibernate? windows forms application or web based?

Comment: entity framework. I want to test a succeed insert.

Comment: If your test is hitting a database, it's not a unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)?  You use it to create a Mock objects and Queryable lists of objects so that you don't need to put fake data into your database to test.

Comment: don't I still need to instantiate each object with every value? :S

Comment: Well you can instantiate it with only the values you will use but once you make one you can copy pasta.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/) on how to get going on writing unit tests.  The one thing I think that may help you in regard to your question:

> Mock out all external services and state 
>   Otherwise, behaviour in those external services overlaps multiple tests, and state data means that different unit tests can influence each other’s outcome. 
>   You’ve definitely taken a wrong turn if you have to run your tests in a specific order, or if they only work when your database or network connection is active. 
>   (By the way, sometimes your architecture might mean your code touches static variables during unit tests. Avoid this if you can, but if you can’t, at least make sure each test resets the relevant statics to a known state before it runs.)